# hosting flask_restplus Swagger UI on Herokuapp says "No API Definition provided."

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I'm trying to host the Swagger UI of Flask Restplus on Heroku server. It builds successfully and when checked in the logs of the heroku, even there it says "Build succeeded".

But the problem is when I check the actual hosting there's just a msg on the page saying 
**No API definition provided**.

[image]
Btw the swagger-UI loads successfully on the browser when run locally.

Following is a sample code snipet for swagger-ui

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@api.route('/hello')
class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)) 
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port, debug=True)
```

So what am I doing wrong here? Is there any way that you can host a simple minimal flask_restplus swagger-UI on **heroku** ? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**

Following is the content of the swagger.json

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "basePath": "/",
    "paths": {
        "/hello": {
            "get": {
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Success"
                    }
                },
                "operationId": "get_hello_world",
                "tags": [
                    "default"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "info": {
        "title": "API",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "produces": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "consumes": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "default",
            "description": "Default namespace"
        }
    ],
    "responses": {
        "ParseError": {
            "description": "When a mask can't be parsed"
        },
        "MaskError": {
            "description": "When any error occurs on mask"
        }
    }
}
```

Also if it helps, this is what's inside the `Procfile`

```
web: python app.py
```

Comment: `ctrl+shift+i` or `F12` what does the browser console say? Have you tried the `appname.herokuapp.com/hello` endpoint? Add the content of `package.json` to your question.

Comment: @TinNguyen the endpoints are working. But the Swagger-UI never shows up when hosted on Heroku. I have tried looking into `ctrl+shift+i` and `F12` also.

Comment: @TinNguyen I have added the contents of `package.json` to the question

Comment: That's not `package.json` that's `swagger.json` but you can leave it in the question.

Comment: I could only find `swagger.json`. Can you help me with where I can find the `package.json` ?

Comment: Oh wait I'm sorry. That's python. Can you provide your requirements.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting what worked for me, just in case if someone has the same concern in future.

I changed the `Procfile` from

```
web: python app.py
```

to

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

and then the swagger-UI first page also started showing up on heroku. Earlier the endpoints were still accessible but the first page ie. the swagger-UI page wasn't showing up. But making this change got it working.